# Recovering a differential operator using Laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I am self-studying differential equations using MIT's publicly available materials.  If $P$ is a monic polynomial of degree $n$ and if $y$ is a solution to the differential equation $p(D)y = 0$ (where $D$ is the differential operator) and we have initial conditions

\begin{align}
y(0) = 1 \qquad y'(0) = y''(0) = \cdots = y^{(n-1)}(0) = 0,
\end{align}
we are asked to show that if

a)  $P(0) = 0$, we can discover nothing from $\mathcal{L}[y](s) = Y(s)$ about the coefficients of $p$; but if

b) $P(0) \neq 0$, then $P$ is uniquely determined by $Y(s)$.

I feel like I'm teetering on the brink of a solution, but somehow I can't quite fall into it.  Here's what I've done:

Let $p = x^n + a_1x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_n$.  It is evident that
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}[y^{(j)}](s) & = s^jY(s) - s^{(j-1)}
\end{align}
for $j = 1, \ldots, n$.  So taking the Laplace transform of both sides of our differential equation, we have
\begin{align}
(s^nY(s) - s^{(n-1)}) + a_1(s^{(n-1)}Y(s) -s^{(n-2)}) + \cdots + a_{n-1}(sY(s) - 1) + a_nY(s) & = 0\Rightarrow\\
  Y(s)(s^n + a_1s^{n-1} + \cdots + a_n) - (s^{n-1} + a_1s^{n-2} + \cdots + a_{n-1}) & = 0\\
  P(s)Y(s) - (s^{n-1} + a_1s^{n-2} + \cdots + a_{n-1}) & = 0.
\end{align}
And setting $s = 0$, we get
\begin{align}
P(0)Y(0) & = a_{n-1}\Rightarrow\\
a_{n-1} & = 0.
\end{align}
if $P(0) = 0$.  This seems wrong, for consider the case $n = 1$.  $P(0) = 0$ means we in fact have $P(x) = x$ -- that is, $a_{n-1} = a_0 = 1$.

No doubt I'm missing something elementary here--I'd appreciate some help figuring out exactly what.

Comment: Given that you're considering a special case to detect an error, it seems like the simplest thing to do is try your argument to $P(x)=x$ directly. In that case $y'(x)=0\implies sY(s)-1=0$. Then $Y(s)=1/s$, so the limit $s\to 0$ isn't valid. So what this shows is that if $P(0)=0$, then either $a_{n-1}=0$ _or_ $Y(s)$ diverges at $s=0$.

Comment: you said that $P(s) Y(s) - \frac{P(s)-1}{s} = 0$ ? so that $Y(s) = \frac{P(s)-1}{s P(s)} = \frac{1-\frac{1}{P(s)}}{s}$  and $P(s) = \frac{1}{1-sY(s)}$

Comment: @user1952009 I'm sorry -- for whatever reason, your comment is cut off.  I think you're on the right track, though I believe that I what we actually have is $P(s)Y(s) - \frac{P(s) - a_n}{s} = 0$.

Comment: @solitaireartist yes right, and $a_n = P(0)$, $Y(s) = \frac{P(s)-P(0)}{s P(s)}$, end of proof (next time, write $P(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$ please)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With credit to Semiclassical and user1952009, we can continue from where I stopped to obtain

\begin{align}
P(s)Y(s) - \frac{P(s) + a_n}{s} & = 0\Rightarrow\\
P(s)(sY(s) - 1) - a_n & = 0\Rightarrow\\
P(s) & = \frac{P(0)}{sY(s) - 1}
\end{align}

which shows that $P(s)$ is completely determined by $Y(s)$ unless $P(0) = 0$, because if $P(0) = 0$,
\begin{align}
Y(s) = \frac{P(s) + P(0)}{sP(s)}
\end{align}
which is undefined at $s = 0$.